# Slow mysql select

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `game_entries` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `player_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `game_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `hero_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `game_avg_pts` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `game_season` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `game_length` smallint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `game_mode` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `game_is_tb` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `game_map` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `game_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `game_playersnum` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `side` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `won` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pts` smallint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pts_change` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `kills` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deaths` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `assists` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `creeps` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `towers` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `player_game` (`player_id`,`game_id`),
  KEY `index_game` (`game_id`),
  KEY `index_player` (`player_id`),
  KEY `index_hero` (`hero_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11706564 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The table has more than 11M rows.
When I try to select all game_entries for a specific player_id, the query takes too long:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `game_entries` WHERE player_id = 4;
227 rows in set (1.68 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM `game_entries` WHERE player_id = 4 LIMIT 25;
25 rows in set (0.27 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `game_entries` WHERE player_id = 4;
+----+-------------+--------------+------+--------------------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys            | key         | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+--------------------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | game_entries | ref  | player_game,index_player | player_game | 4       | const |  226 |       |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+--------------------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is there any way to improve the speed of this query?

Comment: first thing Select fields which are required do not add `* `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider making `{player_id, game_id}` the primary key instead to take advantage of the ["clustering" feature](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html) on innoDb primary key.

That would keep game records for the same player "near" each other and make searches on `player_id = ?` faster.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to add an index on `player_id` column.

Second, if possible, you can mention the limited fields in select query instead of `*`

Comment: But there is `KEY index_player (player_id)`, isn't it an index on `player_id` column?

Comment: @TycoooN - As far as I know, only primary key is indexed by default. Not sure if the unique key as described for player_id is indexed automatically or not. You may have to explicitly add an index on `player_id`